# Can you use two contractions in a row in a sentence?

Tags: contractions

Can you use two contractions in a row?  For example, could you say, "Let's don't do that"?

Comment: And even [two contractions queued together](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions) or [three](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_triple_contractions).

Comment: We don't say "Let's don't do that". British people may sometimes say "Don't let's do that", but more often will say "Let's not do that".

Comment: There’s no reason you shouldn’t be able to you two contractions in a row – why wouldn’t you? But in most forms of English, “let’s don’t” isn’t grammatical, no. Not because it’s two contractions, but because _let_ takes an infinitive complement, and infinitives are negated by preposing _not_, not with _do_-support. So the negative of _let us do that_ is _let us not do that_ (or _do not let us do that_ if you negate the main verb), never _*let us do not do that_.

Comment: Also, _couldn't've_

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this isn't correct, because the auxiliary doesn't fit in that expression.  However, this is a colloquial phrase that one does hear from time to time.  Personally, it doesn't bother me.

The tone is little bit condescending, the way I've heard it used.  A more neutral tone would be "It might be better not to do that" or "We would be better advised not to do that," etc.